# Positive lower bounds for $|x+y|^2 -|x|^2$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, vectors

Let $x, y\in\mathbb{R}^3$ two nonnull vectors. I am looking for some positive lower bounds for
$$|x+y|^2 -|x|^2,$$

where $|\cdot|$ stand for the magnitude of the vector.

$\textbf{My attempt:}$
By using the definition, I got
$$(x_1 +y_1)^2 +(x_2 +y_2)^2+(x_3 +y_3)^2 -x_1^2 -x_2^2 -x_3^2 = |y|^2 +2x_1 y_1 +2 x_2 y_2 +2x_3 y_3 = |y|^2 +2\sum_i x_iy_i $$
but I think it is not so much useful to find some lower bounds.

Could someone please help?

Thank you in advance.

$\textbf{EDIT:}$ I missed to ask if there exists a positive lower bound for the similar case
$$|x|^2 -|x-y|^2.$$

If someone would answer (or edit its answer), it would be great. If not, I will post a new question.

Comment: can you think of vector y such that |x+y| = |x| ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever norm you chose on $\Bbb R^3$ (or on any real vector space)
$$\forall x\ne0\quad\min_{y\ne0}\left(\|x+y\|-\|x\|\right)=-\|x\|$$
(attained for $y=-x$) hence
$$\inf_{x,y\ne0}\left(\|x+y\|-\|x\|\right)=\inf_{x\ne0}\left(-\|x\|\right)=-\infty.$$

Comment: Anne Bauval, thank you for the answer. By following your argument, it follows that $|x|^2>|x-y|^2$ is always verified or not? If this is not the case, under which assumptions on $y$ it should be? Thank you.

Comment: My argument does not suggest that. You have $\|x\|\le\|x-y\|$ for instance when $y=-tx$ with $t\ge0.$ There are no "simple" necessary and sufficient conditions for the inequality $\|x\|>\|x-y\|,$ which can already be considered as simple. It can be interpreted as: $y$ is inside the open ball of radius $\|x\|$ centered at $x.$

Answer (score 2):

There is no positive lower bound, you can make both $|y|^2$ and $2\langle x,y \rangle$ as small as you want. Infact there is no non-positive lower bound either, since $\langle x,y \rangle$ can also be made as negative as you want.